# Proving a certain limit for uniformly integrable random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, uniform-integrability

There is an interesting problem that has been resisting my efforts for a while. Assume that 
$\{X_n: n = 1, 2, \ldots\} $ is a sequence of uniformly integrable random variables. I would like to show that
$$ \lim_n \frac{1}{n}\cdot E\left[\sup_{1\le i \le n} |X_i|\,\right] = 0. $$

Of course $\lim_n \frac{1}{n} \sup_{1\le i \le n} E[|X_i| ] = 0, $
but the limit above, albeit it might very well be as easy, I do not seem to find the way to establish its validity....

I wonder if anyone has an easy proof for this fact. Thank you.

Maurice

Answer (score 2):

Notice that for a fixed $R$, 
$$\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}|X_i|\leqslant\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}|X_i|\chi\{|X_i|\lt R\}+\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}|X_i|\chi\{|X_i|\geqslant R\}\leqslant R+\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}|X_i|\chi\{|X_i|\geqslant R\},$$
hence, taking the expectation and using the inequality $$\mathbb E\left[\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}Y_i\right]\leqslant n\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}\mathbb E[Y_i]$$
valid for non-negative random variables $(Y_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$, we obtain 
$$\mathbb E\left[\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}|X_i|\right]\leqslant R+
n\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}\mathbb E\left[|X_i|\chi\{|X_i|\geqslant R\}\right].$$
Dividing by $n$, we obtain for each $R$
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac 1n\mathbb E\left[\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}|X_i|\right]\leqslant \sup_{i\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[|X_i|\chi\{|X_i|\geqslant R\}\right]$$
and we conclude using the assumption of uniform integrability.